# How to open Yahoo messenger link from iphone app

Tags: iphone

How can i open the following Yahoo messenger link from an iphone app

ymsgr:sendim?testlink

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo messenger app needs to be installed on the device, if so the following works

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ymsgr:sendim?username@yahoo.com"]];
```